# DLL Reference compile error AX2009

Tags: dll, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

I have added a DLL to AX2009. I have placed the DLL in the bin folder for the server and added a reference from in the CUS layer. When I compile the code from the CUS layer, then it compiles fine. Although, when I try and compile the code from the USR layer, then it the compiler is giving an error over code lines where the DLL is referenced. It seems as if the DLL is not recognized from the USR layer.

What is the reason that from the CUS layer, the code compiles fine, but from the USR layer, it does not compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out that the DLL needs to be placed in the bin folder from the client on which the code with the DLL is being compiled.

Comment: You can also place the DLL in the windows GAC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz(v=vs.110).aspx